# When are "how do I learn X" type questions on topic here?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I recently encountered the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59670043/beginner-here-tips-to-improve-my-knowledge-in-java-developing) on Stack Overflow:

> I'm studying and I want to learn how to code in Java, but while my mates are doing arrays, I still continue with the basics - stuff like how to declare variables, how to create a constructor, etc. I have time to learn well but its hard to start, so just want some tips, projects or whatever you think could help people like me, I would be very grateful.

It was closed as "opinion-based" and explained in the comments that these questions tend not to work very well on Stack Overflow.

With that said, is there any possible way for questions like this to be edited to be on-topic here? (I assume that it would have to be more specific for one thing). Should we suggest to OPs that they ask questions on this type of topic here, and what guidance should we give them on how to make their questions acceptable to be posted here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions like this are topical here under the [self-learning](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning) tag, though the question you've quoted is far too broad. If OP wants help on how to cement his understanding of variables, or of constructors, or anything specific, OP can come and ask and we will direct them towards resources or exercises.